# OCaml illiterate in need of record manipulation assistance

Tags: ocaml, command-line-arguments, record

This is a little embarrassing but I've been shown an OCaml program where I know what I want to do but I cannot find the documentation to help me write what I want in the right syntax as I've never used the language before.

I made quite a few working changes to the program and this happens to be the last change I need to make and I cannot work it out!

There is an record of a sort (the syntax used had thrown me off) named `caps_default`:

```
let caps_default =
    {
        browserName = Firefox ;
        version = "" ;
        platform = ANY ;
        username = "" ;
        accessKey = "" ;
        javascriptEnabled = true
    }
;;
```

Then these variables are defined to receive the command line arguments:

```
exception Incorrect_cmdline of string option
;;

let browser_name   = ref ""
and hub_url_opt    = ref ""
and target_url_opt = ref ""
and xml_out_string = ref ""
and user_name      = ref ""
and access_key     = ref ""
;;
```

I added two new arguments named 'username' and 'accessKey' and I want to add them to a "caps" record thing.

Continuing on, here the command line arguments are parsed:

```
let (target_url, hub_url, caps, xml_out) =
    try
        parse_cmdline
            [
                ( noshort , "browser-name" , None, (atmost_once browser_name   (Incorrect_cmdline (Some "browser-name"))) ) ;
                ( noshort , "hub-url"      , None, (atmost_once hub_url_opt    (Incorrect_cmdline (Some "hub-url"))) ) ;
                ( noshort , "target-url"   , None, (atmost_once target_url_opt (Incorrect_cmdline (Some "target-url"))) ) ;
                ( noshort , "xml-output"   , None, (atmost_once xml_out_string (Incorrect_cmdline (Some "xml-output"))) ) ;
                ( noshort , "username"     , None, (atmost_once user_name      (Incorrect_cmdline (Some "username"))) ) ;
                ( noshort , "accessKey"    , None, (atmost_once access_key     (Incorrect_cmdline (Some "accessKey"))) ) ;
                ( noshort , "help"         , Some (fun s -> raise (Incorrect_cmdline None)) , None );
            ]
            ( fun x -> raise (Incorrect_cmdline None)) ;
        ignore (List.map
                (fun s -> if BatString.is_empty !s then raise (Incorrect_cmdline None) else () )
                [ browser_name ; hub_url_opt ; target_url_opt ] );
        let target_url =
            try
            Neturl.parse_url !target_url_opt
            with
            Neturl.Malformed_URL ->
            raise (Incorrect_cmdline (Some ("Invalid target url: " ^ !target_url_opt)))
        and hub_url =
            try
            Neturl.parse_url !hub_url_opt
            with
            Neturl.Malformed_URL ->
            raise (Incorrect_cmdline (Some ("Invalid hub url: " ^ !hub_url_opt)))
        and xml_out =
            if BatString.is_empty !xml_out_string
            then fun s -> ignore s
            else
            let chan = open_out !xml_out_string in
            (fun xml ->
            output_string chan (Xml.to_string xml) ;
            close_out chan )
        (* Continued below *)
```

My desire is to take my new command line argument options `username` and `accessKey`, assigned to the variables `user_name` and `access_key`, to be transmitted to the `caps` record that is defined in the let assignments below:

```
        (* Continued from above *)
        and caps =
            { caps_default with username = !user_name }   (* My addition *)
            { caps_default with accessKey = !access_key } (* My addition *)
            match !browser_name with   (* This switch is original and worked *)
            | "firefox"   -> { caps_default with browserName = Firefox }
            | "chrome"    -> { caps_default with browserName = Chrome }
            | "html_unit" -> { caps_default with browserName = HtmlUnit }
            | "ie"        -> { caps_default with browserName = InternetExplorer }
            | "iphone"    -> { caps_default with browserName = IPhone }
            |  _        -> raise (Incorrect_cmdline (Some ("Invalid browser name: " ^ !browser_name)))
        in
        (target_url, hub_url, caps, xml_out)
    with
        Incorrect_cmdline arg ->
            (match arg with | None -> () | Some msg -> print_endline msg) ;
            print_synopsis () ;
            exit 48
;; (* End of relevant code *)
```

Experimenting I could comment out the original author's switch for --browser-name and assign a single value by putting a solemn line surrounded by curly braces:

```
and caps=
    { caps_default with browserName = Chrome } (* Hard-coding a Chrome choice *)
```

or

```
and caps=
    { caps_default with username = !user_name } (* Sharing only --username *)
```

or

```
and caps=
    { caps_default with accessKey = !access_key } (* Sharing only --accessKey *)
```

Can someone point me in the correct direction? I want to keep the switch the original author wrote but also transmit the `username` and `accessKey` strings to the `caps` record on top of that. Can I change the `caps` object later? Can I modify `default_caps` beforehand and then copy it to `caps`?

This code is only run once per execution, so modifying the `default_caps` object is of absolutely no concern, even if it's not very kosher to do so.

Thanks for any assistance!

**Update**

Numerous thanks to Dr. Scofield's assistance so far. Curiously I am now being met with a slightly different error complaining about what I can only assume is a mis-match of type. Here is the content of the error:

```
File "tester.ml", line 110, characters 40-47:
Error: This expression has type Selenium.Json_client.capabilities
       but an expression was expected of type Selenium.Json_client.browser
```

Line 110 is

```
{ caps_default with browserName = browser;
```

in Mr. Scofield's code snippet, with 40-47 being `browser`.

The definition of `default_caps`'s type `capabilities` is as such:

```
type capabilities =
  {
    browserName       : browser  ;
    version           : string   ;
    platform          : platform ;
    javascriptEnabled : bool     ;
    username          : string   ;
    accessKey         : string   ;
  }
```

And similarly, the type `browser`:

```
type browser =
  Chrome | Firefox | HtmlUnit | InternetExplorer | IPhone
```

The mli (interface, correct?) definitions are identical if that is important.

**Update part 2**

Minor correction only needed to simplify the code from this:

```
match !browser_name with
| "firefox"   -> { caps_default with browserName = Firefox }
| "chrome"    -> { caps_default with browserName = Chrome }
| "html_unit" -> { caps_default with browserName = HtmlUnit }
| "ie"        -> { caps_default with browserName = InternetExplorer }
| "iphone"    -> { caps_default with browserName = IPhone }
|  _        -> raise (Incorrect_cmdline (Some ("Invalid browser name: " ^ !browser_name)))
```

to this:

```
match !browser_name with
| "firefox"   -> Firefox
| "chrome"    -> Chrome
| "html_unit" -> HtmlUnit
| "ie"        -> InternetExplorer
| "iphone"    -> IPhone
|  _        -> raise (Incorrect_cmdline (Some ("Invalid browser name: " ^ !browser_name)))
```

Before continuing with:

```
in
{ caps_default with browserName = browser;
                    username    = !user_name;
                    accessKey   = !access_key;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to learn a little more OCaml than you want to to do this :-)

The thing named `caps_default` is a record, i.e., it has a record type. You're going to have to find the definition of this record type and add your new capabilities to it.

**Update**

OK, you already had the record type fixed up. Here's some code

```
    and caps =
        let browser = 
            match !browser_name with
            | "firefox"   ->  Firefox
            | "chrome"    ->  Chrome
            | "html_unit" ->  HtmlUnit
            | "ie"        ->  InternetExplorer
            | "iphone"    ->  IPhone
            |  _        ->
                raise (Incorrect_cmdline
                   (Some ("Invalid browser name: " ^ !browser_name)))
        in
        { caps_default with browserName = browser;
                            username = !user_name;
                            accessKey = !access_key;
        }
    in
    (target_url, hub_url, caps, xml_out)
```

(Needless to say, this is untested code.)

**Update 2**

(Fixed spelling of `user_name`, thanks.)

Comment: Ah, I was suspecting it to be a record, I did that already and I gave them both string types, thankfully. Alas I'm still at a loss on how to properly assign my received command line arguments to `caps` and maintain the existing switch.

Comment: This is great help so far. But curiously I've run into one more wrinkle concerning type mis-match. I've updated the original question with a new portion at the end.

Comment: My original code had errors. Look at above code again. (Sorry.)

Comment: A-ha! Yes, I see where it went wrong. Thank you very much Mr. Scofield, this seems to work perfectly well for my needs. I'd up-vote your answer but apparently I need 2 more rep to do it, hah. 
PS: One other tiny correction is `!username` when it should be `!user_name` for anyone who may see this later as a guide.